# method removes 2 arguments, but should only be 1

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a method which will remove item from list, but when I am trying to choose which one I want remove I get error

````
(TypeError: rent() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given)```
````

```
account.rent(2)
```

When I leave it with no id `account.rent()`, then method removes 2 first items from list.

Method:

```
def rent(self):
        if(self.logged==True):
            for id in lib.bib.BookList:
                lib.bib.BookList.remove(id)
        else:
            print("No Access")
```

List:

```
library.BookList.insert(0,"Book n1")
library.BookList.insert(1,"Book n2")
library.BookList.insert(2,"Book n3")
```

account.rent() and list is in main.py, def rent(self) in account.py.

I don't know where I declared removing 2 arguments.

Comment: `rent` is defined with only one argument: `self`, the instance that it belongs to, which is passed implicitly. Why do you expect it to take two? Also, it's not a good idea to delete items from a list that you are iterating over

Comment: What would you expect the `2` in `account.rent(2)` to be used for? The method doesn't make any use of any such parameter.

Comment: I was trying to add other argument like ```def rent(self,bib)```,```def rent(self,lib)``` or even ```def rent(self,BookList)``` but with same result

Comment: @ThierryLathuille ```account.rent(2)``` should, in my opinion, remove second element from BookList

Comment: To be honest, I am trying to make method which will be removes  x element from A list and add x element to B list

Comment: You shouldn't remove from lists while iterating them, anyway - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: _trying to add other argument like..._ Those are all correct, if you want to give a parameter to the function, so what **other** error did you get?

Comment: No more errors, just only one "TypeError: rent() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> don't know where I [made it] remove 2 arguments.

Because you have a list of length 3, and removed all but one because that's how the for loop works.

I don't think you need a loop, but see this post about how to properly do that - [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

> account.rent(2) should, in my opinion, remove second element from BookList

If that is want you want, then use `del`

```
def rent(self, position):
    if self.logged and (0 < position < len(lib.bib.BookList)):
        del lib.bib.BookList[position]
    else:
        print("No Access")
```

Comment: I know how to slice the list, but I have no idea what howMuch is?

Comment: "You should slice the list if you want to remove the first few items, not loop over it" in account.rent() i want to remove only one item, chosen by me by id in list

Comment: `howMuch` is a parameter name I chose based on what you wrote in the question. If you want to remove "all elements with an `ID==x`", then you have no `ID` field in what you've inserted in the `BookList`... If you want to remove **an index**, then that would be `del lib.bib.BookList[position]`

Comment: That ``` (0 < position < len(lib.bib.BookList))``` helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def rent(self, book):
    if(self.logged==True):
        if book in self.lib.bib.BookList:
            self.lib.bib.BookList.remove(book)
    else:
        print("No Access")
```

edited

Comment: 1) This assumes that equality checks against the list elements are enforced 2) `.remove()` will work even without the `if` check.

Answer (score 0):

In your rent function, in the remove loop, your array is changed after each remove call. this function remove even element from your array.
assume `a = ['n0', 'n1, 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5']`

in first iteration first element of the array is remove and after first remove call, first element is remove and we have `a = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5']`

in second iteration second element of array a (`['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5']`) is remove and after second remove call, we have `a = ['n1', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5']`.

Remove an item from a list in Python (clear, pop, remove, del)

1- Remove all items: clear()

2- Remove an item by index and get its value: pop()

3- Remove an item by value: remove()

4- Remove items by index or slice: del.

5- Remove items that meet the condition: List comprehensions.